# Program seg faults on vector access

Tags: c++, vector

I am a C++ newbie, learning C++ on a OS X Yosemite.

I was declaring a vector in source file like this.

```
vector <int> v(3);
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void printVector (vector <int> v) {

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size() ; i++)
        cout << v[i] << endl;
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {

    vector<int> v(3);

    cout << "Initialise vectors..." << endl;

    v[0] = 10;
    v[1] = 11;
    v[2] = 12;

    printVector(v);

    v.push_back(7);

    cout << "push back (7)" << endl;

    printVector(v);


    return 0;

}
```

Program worked.

I then referenced this webpage [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/) and followed its way to declare the vector like this.

```
vector <int> v;
```

Compiled (using g++) fine but program segfaults 11 when executed.

Is the website wrong?

Comment: You're going to need to present more code than that. Perhaps you tried to access `a` like so: `a[n] | 0 <= n < 4` in which the first program would have worked and the second one no.

Comment: "compiler seg faults" != "program segfaults when executed"

Comment: Can someone please tell me why I was downvoted? Because of the downvoting, I'm not able to ask questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you access the elements like this:

```
v[0] = 10;
v[1] = 11;
v[2] = 12;
```

This requires the `vector` to have at least three elements. If you declare it like this:

```
vector<int> v(3);
```

Then it has three elements, great. If you declare it like this:

```
vector<int> v;
```

Then it has no elements, so the above accesses are invalid. If you want to create an empty `vector` then add elements to it, use `push_back`:

```
v.push_back(10);
v.push_back(11);
v.push_back(12);
```

Comment: as "the website" says. OP did not follow instructions

Answer (score 2):

When you declare `vector<int> a`, it has size 0, so accessing elements of the vector would produce an error. In that case, you must use `push_back` to add elements:

```
v.push_back(10); // instead of v[0] = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `vector::at` instead of [] operator to have boundary check performed by container. It will throw `out_range_exception` if you cross them.